# Перенос праздничных дней

Tags: java, calendar

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо сделать так, чтоб при выпадании дня на праздничный день, дата сдвинулась на следующий день.

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();

    for (int i=0; i<=6; i++){
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            cal.add(Calendar.SATURDAY,-1);
        } 
    }
    System.out.println((cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+" "+
      symbols.getMonths()[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)]+" "+
      cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+", "+
      symbols.getWeekdays()[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)])
    );
```

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под праздничными днями?

Comment: Красные дни календаря, например 8 Марта

Comment: Стандартного подхода нет, ибо праздничные дни — понятие растяжимое. В каждой стране/регионе/отрасли праздники будут свои. Можете просто сохранять где-то список и сдвигать сверяясь по нему.

Comment: как сделать применимо к 8 Марта например?

Comment: Добавляете список праздничных дней и уже с ним сравниваете!

Comment: примером не могли бы пжл (8 Марта)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берите библиотеку [JollyDay](https://github.com/svendiedrichsen/jollyday) - он поддерживает русские праздники:

```
HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance(HolidayCalendar.RUSSIA);
Set<Holiday> holidays = m.getHolidays(2017);
for(Holiday holiday:holidays) {
    System.out.println("Это какой-то праздник: "+holiday.getDate());
}
```

Comment: не могли бы пжл скинуть ссылку на JollyDay, может у Вас более подробная инфа

Answer (score 0):

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();

    Calendar h = new GregorianCalendar();
    h.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
    h.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);
    for (int i=0; i<=6; i++){
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.SATURDAY) {
        cal.add(Calendar.SATURDAY,-1);
    } else if (cal.get(Calendar.DATE)== h.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        } 
            System.out.println((cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+" "+symbols.getMonths()[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)]+" "+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+", "+symbols.getWeekdays()[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]));
```

}